# Is it possible to call phtml of backend in frontend?

Tags: phtml

I want to call two phtml in frondend which is admin side phtml

is it possible to call phtml of backend in customer account?

if yes than i want to call this two phtml:

```
adminhtml\default\default\template\downloadable/product/edit/downloadable/samples.phtml

adminhtml\default\default\template\downloadable/product/edit/downloadable/links.phtml
```

how to call this phtml?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In theory you can do it, I think, by emulating the backend for a frontend area.
You can do the emulation like this:

```
$adminStoreId = 0;
$appEmulation = Mage::getSingleton('core/app_emulation');
$initialEnvironmentInfo = $appEmulation->startEnvironmentEmulation($adminStoreId); 
//your magic here
//then stop the emulation
$appEmulation->stopEnvironmentEmulation($initialEnvironmentInfo);
```

But this is not a good practice. If you have urls in the templates you mentioned then they will be generated using the admin helper and you end up with a strainge `key` parameter.
Not to mention that it may not fit with your design.
I suggest you just clone the templates to frontend and keep frontend separate from backend.

Comment: awasome concept @marius

Comment: @AmitBera. It's not mine :) Magento thought of it.

Comment: nice catch @Marius